# 14.04: after a recent update, bash completion is broken in specific cases

Tags: command-line, bash

After some unspecified point in the past, my bash completion has acted strangely:

- if I begin a filename to complete with `~/`, I cannot complete filenames, only directory names, and the suggested names (if I press tab twice) show only directories (including hidden ones)
- sometimes, under random circumstances, completing relative paths also has the above restrictions (most recently, trying to complete while in a subdirectory of /tmp exhibited this behavior)
- if I start a command line as `VAR= -l(space)` for any `VAR` and `-l` and press tab, bash-complete throws up its "unknown argument/incorrect syntax" help message (in my case, I wanted to tab-complete an `LDFLAGS=-L/...` whose spaces would be removed once I found the directory that had the libraries)

Everything else (completing absolute pathnames, command completion, etc.) works as expected. I do **not** have the `/dir(space)` tab-completion behavior that other questions about bash-complete found here and on Google cover.

I tried removing /etc/bash_completion.d to no avail. `sudo apt-get --reinstall install bash-complete` did not work either. `complete -r` restores the intended behavior, so it is an issue with bash_completion... this has persisted across several updates to the bash-completion package as well.

I am on Kubuntu 14.04; this happens both in Konsole and in virtual terminals.

What could be going on? Thanks!